# Residue of $\frac {e^{sz}} {e^z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm usually okay with calculating residues but in this case the denominator isn't a polynomial and I'm not sure what to do.

Can someone tell me how to calculate the residue of $\dfrac {e^{sz}} {e^z+1}$ at z=$\pi$$i$?

Comment: What is the range of $s$?

Comment: The range for s is 0<Re(s)<1

Comment: The residue at which point?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that! The point I'm interested in is pi*i

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $z = \pi i$ you have $e^{\pi i} = -1$

$z = \pi i$ is then a pole.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Assume $0<\Re s<1$.

Observe that
$$
e^z=-1 \iff z=i(2n+1) \pi,\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$ Then the poles are simple and one may use the [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles):
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,c) = \frac{g(c)}{h'(c)},$$
giving

> $$
> \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac {e^{sz}} {e^z+1},i(2n+1) \pi\right)=\frac{e^{is(2n+1)\pi}}{e^{i(2n+1)\pi}}=-e^{is(2n+1)\pi},\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}.
> $$

Thus, one gets

> $$
> \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac {e^{sz}} {e^z+1},i\pi\right)=\frac{e^{is(2n+1)\pi}}{e^{i(2n+1)\pi}}=-e^{is\pi}=-\cos (\pi s)-i\sin(\pi s).
> $$

Comment: I see, thank you so much!